# Auto Relacionamento no EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, code-first

Estou tendo o seguinte problema ao criar duas auto relações.

Ao rodar o *Update-Database* Aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'Autorelação.Franquia' and 'Autorelação.Franquia'. The principal
>   end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations.

*Minha Classe*

```
public class Franquia
    {
        [Key]
        public int FranquiaId { get; set; }

        public int? FranquiaMasterId { get; set; }

        public int? FranquiaSeniorId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FranquiaMasterId")]
        public virtual Franquia FranquiaMaster { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FranquiaSeniorId")]
        public virtual Franquia FranquiaSenior { get; set; }
    }
```

Detalhe, ao rodar apenas um auto relacionamento funciona perfeitamente, entretanto com os dois aparece o erro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seguindo sua linha de raciocínio, uma `Franquia` poderá ter uma lista de franquias, e é exatamente o que está faltando quando você utilizada `DataAnnotations`.

Para isso, você deve utilizar também a anotação [`InverseProperty`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) para realizar o mapeamento adequado das propriedades de navegação.

Seu código ficará da seguinte forma:

```
public class Franquia
    {
        [Key]
        public int FranquiaId { get; set; }

        public int? FranquiaMasterId { get; set; }

        public int? FranquiaSeniorId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FranquiaMasterId")]
        public virtual Franquia FranquiaMaster { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FranquiaSeniorId")]
        public virtual Franquia FranquiaSenior { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("FranquiaMaster")]
        public ICollection<Franquia> FranquiasMasters { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("FranquiaSenior")]
        public ICollection<Franquia> FranquiasSeniors { get; set; }
    }
```

Existe a possibilidade de fazer por **Fluent API**, que ficaria desta forma:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Franquia>()
    .HasOptional(s => s.FranquiaMaster)
    .WithMany(s => s.FranquiasMasters)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.FranquiaMasterId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Franquia>()
    .HasOptional(s => s.FranquiaSenior)
    .WithMany(s => s.FranquiasSeniors)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.FranquiaSeniorId);
```

Se estiver utilizando `Migrations` e for a criação da tabela, e não alteração, a migration gerada terá esse código:

```
public partial class addFranquias : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Franquias",
            c => new
                {
                    FranquiaId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    FranquiaMasterId = c.Int(),
                    FranquiaSeniorId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.FranquiaId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Franquias", t => t.FranquiaMasterId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Franquias", t => t.FranquiaSeniorId)
            .Index(t => t.FranquiaMasterId)
            .Index(t => t.FranquiaSeniorId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Franquias", "FranquiaSeniorId", "dbo.Franquias");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Franquias", "FranquiaMasterId", "dbo.Franquias");
        DropIndex("dbo.Franquias", new[] { "FranquiaSeniorId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Franquias", new[] { "FranquiaMasterId" });
        DropTable("dbo.Franquias");
    }
}
```

E para completar, terá o seguinte `SQL` que será executado no banco:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Franquias] (
    [FranquiaId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [FranquiaMasterId] [int],
    [FranquiaSeniorId] [int],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Franquias] PRIMARY KEY ([FranquiaId])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_FranquiaMasterId] ON [dbo].[Franquias]([FranquiaMasterId])
CREATE INDEX [IX_FranquiaSeniorId] ON [dbo].[Franquias]([FranquiaSeniorId])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Franquias] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Franquias_dbo.Franquias_FranquiaMasterId] FOREIGN KEY ([FranquiaMasterId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Franquias] ([FranquiaId])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Franquias] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Franquias_dbo.Franquias_FranquiaSeniorId] FOREIGN KEY ([FranquiaSeniorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Franquias] ([FranquiaId])
```

Comment: Deu certo @randrade  realmente estava faltando o `InverseProperty`! Obrigado